# How to implement loops with ## in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation

I have to implement a loop which uses ##.

```
#define  REGISTER_EXPANSION_SIMPLE(erm_register,register_index)  erm_register##register_index.R

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
REGISTER_EXPANSION_SIMPLE(ERM.SR,i);
```

The issue is that since the `REGISTER_EXPANSION_SIMPLE` will be replaced in prepossessing stage, at  that time value of "i" will not be known and expansion will become

`ERM.SRi.R` but I want it `ERM.SR1.R`

Please can you help me fixing the issue. I know it is a logical error. Any help will highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can't, becase you are using marco which is replace in pre-proposse.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, `i` is a run-time variable and not a compile-time constant.

What you can do though, assuming the registers are in adjacent memory cells, is this:

```
#define REGISTER_BASE  ((volatile uint8_t*)0x12345678) // uint8_t or uint32_t depending on reg size
#define REGISTER(n)    (*(REGISTER_BASE + n))

...

for(i=0; i<10; i++)
  REGISTER(i) = something;
```